# No entiendo el símbolo [i] en la sintaxis del Lenguaje C en el siguiente algoritmo

Tags: c, algoritmos

¡Hola a tod@s! El siguiente código lo copié de un foro con el propósito de poder invertir cualquier palabra que le ingrese al algoritmo. El problema es que entiendo todo el proceso a exepción de "while (cadena[i] != '\0')", y el siguiente "for" ¿qué le está diciendo al compilador ese bucle?

Hasta ahora entiendo lo siguiente: mientras la cadena de carácteres introducida no sea igual a nada(\0), súmale 1.

Y el for lo interpreto como: j es igual a i, mientras no sea menor o igual a o réstale 1 y retorna el valor en cada iteración.

Otra duda, ¿en el bucle for, la variable i tiene como valor la posición y el caracter asignado? Por ejemplo, ¿en la palabra Hola, i vale 4 y H al mismo momento?

Gracias y disculpen las molestias, soy novato.

````
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char cadena[200];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    printf("Introduce una cadena de texto:\n");
    gets(cadena);
    printf("La cadena introducida es: %s\n\n", cadena);
    while (cadena[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("La cadena al reves es:\n\t");
    for (j = i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        printf("%c", cadena[j]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Como comentario, te recomendaría no copiar y pegar código, muchas veces es erróneo y otras veces no se adecúa a lo que realmente quieres. Por parte de tu duda, C es un lenguaje null terminated, es decir que usa el carácter '\0' para indicar que ahí termina una cadena de texto. Lo único que hace ese while es contar cuántos caracteres tiene la cadena de texto, para evitar ese ciclo podrías hacer uso de strlen

Comment: Gracias por su comentario. ¿Y el uso de [i] a que se refiere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vayamos por partes... Analicemos tu código primero.

1. `gets(cadena);` Esto te permite introducir la cadena que quieras por el teclado y toda esa cadena te la almacena en una variable llamada `cadena`. Esta variable es un array de tipo `char` (carácter) de 200 posiciones, que queda declarado en tu código como: `char cadena[200];`. De este modo tu variable cadena tiene 200 posiciones donde puedes almacenar una letra por posición.
2. Primer `for`:

   while (cadena[i] != '\0')
   {
   i++;
   }
   Esto lo único que hace es "contabilizar" el número de letras que tiene tu cadena. Como bien dices, empieza a ir letra por letra hasta que encuentre el `\0`, que para resumir es como detectar la tecla ENTER.
3. Segundo `for`:

   for (j = i; j >= 0; j--)
   {
   printf("%c", cadena[j]);
   }
   ¿Qué está haciendo? está igualando la variable `j` a la variable `i`, por lo que el primer valor de `j` va a ser la última posición de tu cadena. Date cuenta también que en vez de aumentar `j`, lo que hace es decrementarla con `j--`. Tiene lógica, ¿verdad? Pues si tenemos la cadena `HOLA`, nosotros queremos empezar a mostrar por pantalla la última letra e ir hasta el principio para poder mostrar `ALOH`.

> Otra duda, ¿en el bucle for, la variable i tiene como valor la posición y el caracter asignado? Por ejemplo, ¿en la palabra Hola, i vale 4 y H al mismo momento?

La variable `i` es un entero (porque así está declarada) y te sirve para recorrer todas y cada una de las posiciones de tu cadena, por lo tanto **A LA VARIABLE i SÓLO SE LE ASIGNA EL NÚMERO** que indica la posición de tu array.

Ahora que tenemos esto claro, pongamos un ejemplo... Si introducimos la palabra `HOLA`, nuestro array será:

```
sentido de i ----->
            cadena = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
                      H   O   L   A   \0
```

Con el primer `for` obtenemos la cantidad de letras que hemos introducido, por lo que la variable `i` nos dice cuántas letras hay.
El segundo for nos permite ahora expulsar todas esas letras por pantalla en orden inverso. Igualamos `j` con `i` y recorremos el array desde el final hasta el principio, decrementando `j` con la instrucción `j--`:

```
                          <----- sentido de j
cadena = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
         H   O   L   A   \0
```

Una vuelta de tuerca que mejoraras este ejemplo de tal forma que te indique cuántos caracteres se han introducido, por ejemplo. Que al final del programa te muestre el número total. Te dejo una muestra de lo que te tendría que salir:

```
Introduce una cadena de texto:
HOLA PEPE
La cadena introducida es: HOLA PEPE

La cadena al reves es:
EPEP ALOH
Se han introducido 9 caracteres
```

Ya te digo, este punto final es para que intentes por ti mismo darle una vuelta más y demostrarte a ti mismo que lo has entendido. Mucho ánimo!

Comment: Lo resumiré en dos palabras: te amo. Jajaja